# How to hide the Maven build-phase tool window in IntelliJ 2019.2?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, alert

How can I disable the Maven build-phase tool window either

- (a) *permanently* or
- (b) *temporarily*?

(see screenshot below)

[image: Tool-Window during a Maven-Build in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2]

It was introduced in IntelliJ IDEA`2019.2` (CE & Ultimate) and is activated by default during a Maven build.

My questions are:

1. Is there any change of deactivating this behaviour completely?
2. If not: Can it be configured to show only errors instead of **all** warnings?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, if you do a right-click on that section you can disable the `Show Warnings` option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) - that helped a bit - but total deactivation would be great :D